# Style update issue in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I have a long running Javascript operation for which i need to show the user a "Loading..." message.
I have a div (standbyDiv) which shows the loading message which is always hidden except for when running this operation.
Here is how i am trying to achieve this

```
document.getElementById('standbyDiv').style.display = "";
LongRunningJavascriptLibraryCall();    // runs for about 10 seconds
document.getElementById('standbyDiv').style.display = "none";
```

In Firefox, this works as intended. In Google Chrome, setting the display to on in line 1 does not show up. For whatever reason, Chrome does not refresh the display after line 1. Instead, it waits for lines 2 and 3 to run before the style is applied and standbyDiv never shows up during the operation. If i single step through the lines in the Chrome debugger, it works as intended.

Any ideas?

Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.72

Comment: Have you tried setting up a setTimeout() function to call your long function so that the dom gets a chance to update?

Comment: Are you sure it's taking 10 seconds on Chrome. And is it asynchronous?? What does your function do?

Comment: This call is part of a synchronous stream. It will need to be redesigned to be asynchronous before i can use setTimeout. The long running call is a database fetch operation over network and depending on how much data is being fetched, it could take up to 20 seconds. The exact call is as follows `dojo.safeMixin(this, jsonrpc.JsonQBServiceManager.getQBJob(this.jobId, this.dateObj.stDt, this.dateObj.endDt, this.bidStr));`

Comment: A database call is not synchronous. That's where your issue is.

Comment: The jsonrpc call i am making AFAIK is synchronous in nature. The call returns the results and there is no callback function provided. The actual database call happens many layers below the jsonrpc. Also note that this works in Firefox as intended.

Comment: It's asynchronous. Read the docs. It uses promises.

Comment: Any updates? Did you see the documentation as I recommended?

Comment: JSONRPC makes synchronous calls, unless you pass a callback function as the first param to the call. I have used it both ways and it is making a synchronous call in this case. I used setTimeout to schedule a hide as a workaround. Thanks.
"The RPC client uses asynchronous server calls, if the first argument provided is an object with an onResponse method"

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to either use a callback or a promise to revert the style when the operation is complete:

```
function hide() {
  elem.style.display = 'none';
}

LongRunningJavascriptLibraryCall(hide);

function LongRunningJavascriptLibraryCall(callback) {
  //...
  //when the server call comes back:
  success : function() { //whatever the library uses for a callback
    callback();
  }
}
```

### Old Answer (for synchronous code)

**Set the style to "block" instead of nothing.**

```
document.getElementById('standbyDiv').style.display = "block";
```

**Force a reDraw on the element:**

```
document.getElementById('standbyDiv').style.display = "block";
var x = document.getElementById('standbyDiv').offsetHeight;
```

Just a note on good practices - you could cache your element reference for re-use:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('standbyDiv');

elem.style.display = "";
var x = elem.offsetHeight;
LongRunningJavascriptLibraryCall();
elem.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: I had tried using "block" and it made no difference. Just tried it again along with getting the offsetHeight as in your example  and that didn't help either. Thanks

Comment: @user2453831 if you'll answer my comment, I can help. What does your function do? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: can you explain why you think my code is asynchronous? Chrome does not apply the change in the dom property as it happens. It defers the change to be applied later on.

Comment: @user2453831 the solution will be to find where the asynchronous function is called. It returns a promise, so you can attach a `then` statement to it, like this: `myAsyncFunc().then(function() { hide() }`

Comment: i dont think i understand. The issue is not that the code runs through line 3 (hiding the div) while line 2 (Long Function)is still executing asynchronously. The style change in line 1 (showing the div) is only applied to the dom after line2 is executed. I really believe this is an issue with Chrome deciding to defer redrawing the element after the display value changes.